# Initialising istream attribute with std::string

Tags: c++

I have a class with the attribute `std::istream & _submission;` and a constructor that takes an istream and initializes the attribute. 
Now, I'd like my class to accept a string (not istream). How can i do so? 
It complains that the attribute `_submission` is not initialized (`must explicitly initialize the reference member 'submission_'`)

Current situation: `Parser::Parser(std::istream & input_stream) : submission_(input_stream)`
I would like to have `Parser::Parser(std::string input)`

Comment: My crystal ball says "use the constructor initialization list".

Comment: I have a wife who expects a bottle of wine every evening. Now I'd like to be able to come home with a box of donuts one evening (not wine). How I can do so? She complains that her wine glass isn't filled.

Comment: how can i initialise istream with string?

Comment: haha funny. but really guys, should i use stringstream? 
but how? 
(im new with c++)

Comment: Your class expects to bind a reference to some existing stream. If you have no stream, you can't bind the reference to anything. What do you expect to happen? What does the class do with the stream? What is the std::string argument used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.  Since your data member is only a (non-`const`) *reference*, you cannot bind a temporary `std::istringstream` to it.  (And if you'd manage to do it somehow, it would blow up dramatically.)

What you can do, is to give your type two attributes, a `std::istream&` and a `std::istringstream`.  If you get passed a stream, you don't use the `std::istringstream` but if you get a `std::string`, you initialize the `std::istringstream` with it and bind the reference to it.

```
class MyType
{

public:

  MyType(std::istream& is) : stream_ {is}
  {
  }

  MyType(std::string s) : stringstream_ {std::move(s)}
  {
  }

  // Now you can use stream_ in your other member functions.

private:

  std::istringstream stringstream_ {};

  std::istream& stream_ {stringstream_};
};
```

Note that the declaration oder matters: You must declare the `stringstream_` member *before* the `stream_` member.

Comment: The brace-or-init initializer on the `stringstream_` member is rather redundant, but using `std::istream& stream_{stringstream_}` instead of in the ctor would make sense, and only provide one mem-initializer in each ctor.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I know that the `{}` isn't required here but I like to be explicit.  Your other suggestion is clever, I didn't think of that.  But I'd rather keep the example as above because I find it easier to explain.

Comment: @JonathanWakely You know what, I did it.  It looks nicer.  Thanks!

Comment: :-) you're welcome - I like the symmetry of each constructor only initializing the member that needs the constructor argument, and the other one having a "default" ... although it is a bit subtle, because it's not immediately obvious that you never use both defaults at once, only one or the other.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Actually, you *could* use both at the same time, if a third (default) constructor were added.  It would make kind of sense to have an empty stream initialized in that case.  Of course, it all depends on how the OP wants to use this type.